# How to make lines around piechart position evenly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I put chart lines as pointers to labels around the piechart. Lines are made of 3 points.
I am trying to make horizontal ends of these lines evenly spread vertically so that label values could fit properly. What I need is an algorithm or an advice how to measuring lines points positions so that they could be positioned evenly, like a grid.

[image: Chart]

**UPDATE**

I have simplified the task a bit by making legs vertical, not coming from center of the circle, so that not to waste too much time on achieving the effect. I will prepare a fiddle and update here if anyone is interested.

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I understand you want this specific look...but as an alternative thought or perhaps generator of implementation ideas, you could take a look at how [d3pie](https://github.com/benkeen/d3pie/blob/master/d3pie-source/_labels.js) goes about this issue. The `resolveOuterLabelCollisions` function is the main one dealing with the positional challenges. A thought.

Comment: The update looks nice...I would be interested in seeing the final result in a fiddle. And I would wager I am not the only one :)

Comment: Do you still intend to share your results here or perhaps via bl.ocks.org or a blog post?

Comment: Yup, just preparing it finally, will share today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

What a fun question, I can't resist giving it a quick thinking through.  :-)

Generally speaking...

1. I would first collect and sort the Y coordinates of the black dots in your diagram.
2. Then I would take the median point and work outwards, pushing the higher coordinates up and the lower down as needed, so that there was some minimum space between them (based on text height I assume).
3. Then it is a matter of determining the three points of each label line.  The math wouldn't be too hard as you have the slope from the line from the circle center to the black dot.  Take the sloped line out until you hit your label slot Y.
4. You probably want to split the work and do it twice, once for each vertical half of the chart.

You're after a very pretty look, I like it, good luck.

Comment: just a little addition based from the drawing: 
1- the black dots are at the middle of each arc (maybe this simplifies a bit the thing)
2- the lines reaching out from the pie chart are just radiuses (or radii?) of a bigger circle, and each one of them cuts in half a slice of the pie